# Calculate Levenshtein distance between two strings in Python

Tags: python, edit-distance

I need a function that checks how different are two different strings. I chose the Levenshtein distance as a quick approach, and implemented this function:

```
from difflib import ndiff

def calculate_levenshtein_distance(str_1, str_2):
    """
        The Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference between two sequences.
        It is calculated as the minimum number of single-character edits necessary to transform one string into another
    """
    distance = 0
    buffer_removed = buffer_added = 0
    for x in ndiff(str_1, str_2):
        code = x[0]
        # Code ? is ignored as it does not translate to any modification
        if code == ' ':
            distance += max(buffer_removed, buffer_added)
            buffer_removed = buffer_added = 0
        elif code == '-':
            buffer_removed += 1
        elif code == '+':
            buffer_added += 1
    distance += max(buffer_removed, buffer_added)
    return distance
```

Then calling it as:

```
similarity = 1 - calculate_levenshtein_distance(str_1, str_2) / max(len(str_1), len(str_2))
```

How sloppy/prone to errors is this code? How can it be improved?

Comment: Please note that your function does not exactly implement the Levenshtein distance. A distance is symmetric by definition, but `difflib.ndiff` is not. Hence, the "distance" score is different if you swap the arguments.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a module available for exactly that calculation, [`python-Levenshtein`](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/). You can install it with `pip install python-Levenshtein`.

It is implemented in C, so is probably faster than anything you can come up with yourself.

```
from Levenshtein import distance as levenshtein_distance
```

---

According to the [`docstring` conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), your docstring should look like this, i.e. with the indentation aligned to the `"""` and the line length curtailed to 80 characters.

```
def calculate_levenshtein_distance(str_1, str_2):
    """
    The Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference
    between two sequences.
    It is calculated as the minimum number of single-character edits necessary to
    transform one string into another.
    """
    ...
```

Comment: Just to note the module is licensed under GPL 2.0 so watch out if you're using it for work.

Comment: Just to point out a small nitpick to other people who may stumble upon this answer, as per [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted."   While this answer does provide alternative and existing module suggestion, it also goes into some suggestions about improving code quality. So it's an example of a decent answer

Comment: Thanks! I did not know of this module. Will check it out

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy While I (obviously) agree, and that is one of the reasons I added that part, I would actually argue that "It is implemented in C, so is probably faster than anything you can come up with yourself" would get around the "no explanation or justification" clause

Comment: Upvoted because this answer came up first for _python levenshtein edit distance_ in Google and I'll want to find to find the library link again, but the code review itself could be improved by suggesting something about the algorithm in addition to the doc string formatting.

Comment: @user1717828 While I agree that the review could be improved upon, note that an answer here at Code Review is a valid answer as long as it gives at least one insight regarding the code in the OP, as also noted further up in the comments. I feel like my answer does that and the other answer is quite complementary to it and hits on other, also important points, so I'd rather not repeat the points made there.

Comment: As a faster alternative to python-Levenshtein that is more open licensed https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz (rapidfuzz.string_metric.levenshtein) can be used

Answer (score 17):

The code itself is rather clear. There are some smaller changes I would make

## tuple unpacking

You can use tuple unpacking to do:

```
for code, *_ in ndiff(str1, str2):
```

instead of:

```
for x in ndiff(str_1, str_2):
    code = x[0]
```

## dict results:

Instead of a counter for the additions and removals, I would keep it in 1 dict:     `counter = ({"+": 0, "-": 0})`

```
def levenshtein_distance(str1, str2, ):
    counter = {"+": 0, "-": 0}
    distance = 0
    for edit_code, *_ in ndiff(str1, str2):
        if edit_code == " ":
            distance += max(counter.values())
            counter = {"+": 0, "-": 0}
        else: 
            counter[edit_code] += 1
    distance += max(counter.values())
    return distance
```

## generators

A smaller, less useful variation, is to let this method be a generator, and use the builtin `sum` to do the summary. this saves 1 variable inside the function:

```
def levenshtein_distance_gen(str1, str2, ):
    counter = {"+": 0, "-": 0}
    for edit_code, *_ in ndiff(str1, str2):
        if edit_code == " ":
            yield max(counter.values())
            counter = {"+": 0, "-": 0}
        else: 
            counter[edit_code] += 1
    yield max(counter.values())

sum(levenshtein_distance_gen(str1, str2))
```

---

## timings

The differences in timings between the original and both these variations are minimal, and within the variation of results. This is rather logical, since for simple strings (`aaabbbc` and `abcabcabc`) 90% of the time is spent in `ndiff`

Comment: Awesome suggestions. I had not even considered the generator approach, but it looks very nice. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I used the dict code from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/217074 but if you don't want to implement the method yourself I recommend the edit distance method of nltk  https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.edit_distance.html
over Python-Levenshtein https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/ because of the licensing

Comment: This doesn't seem to review the code - perhaps it should be a comment instead?